MSYS2: Error: Command line contains characters that are not supported in the active code page (1252)
CI code, which is run via the Github Actions, and worked flawlessly for a number of years, started to fail when attempting to pass some unicode characters via the command line.
Test executable is run via the MSYS shell msys2 {0}. Shell itself appears to use utf-8:
Lang:
en_US.UTF-8

chcp.com:
Active code page: 65001

Also test-printing of unicode characters from the shell works correctly:
Printing unicode 1:
✓

Anyone has idea what else could go wrong? Given it worked well previously and started to fail only now it seems to be some issue with MSYS2 update.

The reason of this issue is that after the 20240727 MSYS release changed the way command line arguments are translated from the wide char.
Original reply on the MSYS Github page: https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/22462#issuecomment-2465927832
Patch which changes behaviour: https://github.com/mingw-w64/mingw-w64/commit/0d42217123d3aec0341b79f6d959c76e09648a1e#diff-32a4eaf3a9253a85d560f22d0c4ff81f12df6ef6977450bba36be2415dd425a3R148
Solution is to force utf-8 for executables via the manifest file.
Sample manifest file:
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <asmv3:application>
    <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2019/WindowsSettings"> 
      <activeCodePage>UTF-8</activeCodePage> 
    </asmv3:windowsSettings>
  </asmv3:application>
</assembly>

Sample MSYS shell script to embed manifest file into the executable:
# Add mt.exe (manifest tool) to the PATH
win_sdk=$(reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Kits\Installed Roots" | sort -r | head -n 1 | sed 's/.*\\//')
echo "Windows SDK: $win_sdk"
export PATH="/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/bin/$win_sdk/x64/":$PATH
# Add manifest which forces utf-8 encoding
for exe in "tests/rnp_tests" "rnp/rnp" "rnpkeys/rnpkeys"; do
  mt.exe -manifest ./ci/utf8-manifest "-outputresource:./build/src/${exe}.exe;1" > /dev/null
done

